# Contents of Div Are Displaying Wrong in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html, cross-browser

I'm working on designing a v3 platform for a website. We're almost done, and now were just doing the finishing touches with cross-browser texting. Everything works fine, except for IE.

I'm testing in IE 9, and when the page loads, there is supposed to be a slider at the top of the page. The slider is set up as one long block of images/desrciption text, which jQuery slides on and off the page.

The slider divs work fine, but the **content** of the divs is oddly block displayed on the side. So basically the content of my divs are not showing up inside my divs.

So is there any dort of bug/quirk with IE that causes this.

Example code:

```
<div id="cont">
  <div
    <img src="bar" />
    <a href="foo"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="bar" />
    <a href="foo"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont {
position: relative;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
}

.cont div{
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 980px;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 5;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this, among many of the problems I recently asked about, were simply caused by Internet Explorer's inability to compute more than 31 stylesheets.

So if you have more than 31 stylesheets, beware.